# Catching the exception thrown by python script in shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am having a shell script which opens a file and pass it to python script for processing it. So if there is any issue with the file ( e.g. the file content is not in the format required for the successful execution for python script), the python script throws an exception. Since my objective it to process N files using python script. I need to know which is the file causing the script to break.  I read on how to catch the exception in thrown by command execution. http://linuxcommand.org/wss0150.php . But in my case its the python script which throws the exception and I need to know in shell script what the exception has been thrown. Can anyone help me how can I proceed with this?

Below is the code snippet :

```
#!/bin/bash
yesterday=$(date --date "yesterday" "+%y%m%d")
ftoday=$(date --date "today" "+%m-%d-%Y")
year=$(date "+%Y")
fileList=$(find C:/logdata/$year/$ftoday/ -iname "*"$yesterday".log")
for var in $fileList
do
echo -e "\n START Processing File : $var" >> shelltestlog.txt
cat $var| ./scriptA.py 
echo -e "\n END Processing File : $var" >> shelltestlog.txt
done
```

Comment: If you just want to stop the script when it finds exception and debug right away. Then you can use syntax: 
`./scriptA.py || exit 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your python script returns an non-zero error level whenever it gets an exception, you can use `|| { }` to log messages:

```
./scriptA.py < "$file" || {
    printf "\n Python script scriptA.py failed with file \"%s\".\n" "$file" >> shelltestlog.txt
}
```

I actually tried to simplify your code first:

```
#!/bin/bash

yesterday=$(date --date "yesterday" "+%y%m%d")
ftoday=$(date --date "today" "+%m-%d-%Y")
year=$(date "+%Y")

readarray -t filesList < <(find C:/logdata/$year/$ftoday/ -iname "*"$yesterday".log")

for file in "${filesList[@]}"; do
    printf "\n START Processing File : %s\n" "$file" >> shelltestlog.txt
    ./scriptA.py < "$file" || {
        printf "\n Python script scriptA.py failed with file \"%s\".\n" "$file" >> shelltestlog.txt
    }
    printf "\n END Processing File : %s\n" "$file" >> shelltestlog.txt
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Using above approach , I solved the problem of getting information about the failing file/s. But I was not able to catch the exception thrown by .py script.

Comment: @Codelearner Exceptions don't propagate across process boundaries.  This is the best you can do short of rewriting the entire thing as one Python script as I suggested.

Comment: @Zack, I agree with you. Maybe the approach suggested by Chepner is helpful to get to know the exception details...

Answer (score 2):

An uncaught exception will produce a traceback printed to standard error. The best you can do is capture that, and try to parse it.

```
if ! ./scriptA.py < "$var" 2> stderr.txt; then
  # Parse stderr.txt to see what exception was raised.
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play some redirection games:

```
# open file descriptor 3, pointing to the same destination as stdout
exec 3>&1

# run the script, 
# python's stderr goes to stdout so it can be captured in a variable
# python's stdout goes to file descriptor 3, displayed on the terminal
python_stderr=$( ./scriptA.py < "$var" 2>&1 1>&3 )

# close the file descriptor
exec 3>&-
```

Then you can examine $python_stderr for patterns

```
case $python_stderr in
    "") echo "nothing on stderr" ;;
    *foo*) handle_foo_error ;;
    *bar*) handle_bar_error ;;
    *baz*) handle_baz_error ;;
esac
```

Comment: It's important to do the redirections in the left-to-right order shown.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite the shell script in Python and merge it into the existing Python script.
The stuff that you are currently doing with the `date` command, can be done with the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) modules.  The stuff you are doing with `find` can be done with [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk) and [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch).

Here's an outline:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

def scriptA(file_to_process):
    # the code currently in scriptA goes here;
    # modify it to read from `file_to_process` rather than `sys.stdin`

def get_file_list():
    # your bash logic to construct the file list goes here,
    # converted to Python as suggested above

def main():
   for filename in get_file_list():
       sys.stderr.write("Processing {}...\n".format(filename))
       try:
           scriptA(open(filename, "rt"))

       except SomeExceptionType as e:
           # handle exception...

       except SomeOtherExceptionType as e:
           # handle other kind of exception...

       sys.stderr.write("Done processing {}.\n".format(filename))

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting one more approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a special `$?` variable in bash which contains the exit code of the previous command that was executed. Since you are running a python script inside bash, once the call ends it will generate some exit code.

Now, we need to manually access the exit code which can be found in bash `$?` variable which stores the exit codes. see more [here](https://www.learnshell.org/en/Special_Variables)

It is worth noting that successful execution of a process gives exit code 0. So any other exit code means there was some exception involved in the execution. So you can make use of *if else* here like this:

```
./scriptA.py
if [ $? -gt 0 ] ;then
    # echo "exit code $?"
    # do something with it
else
    # do something else
fi
```

This link is also helpful in understanding [exit codes](https://medium.com/@anupkumarray/working-with-exit-codes-between-python-shell-scripts-177931204291)